# How to add Contact with birth date to Android using Cordova / Phonegap Contacts Plugin

Tags: android, date, cordova, plugins, contacts

We are facing an issue while trying to add birthday to Contact while using Cordova for android while adding a new contact to the phonebook

following is part of the code

```
contact = navigator.contacts.create({
"displayName": displayname
});

// store contact name
var contactName = new ContactName();
contactName.familyName = lastname;
contactName.givenName = firstname
contact.name = contactName;

contact.birthday = new Date("16 May 1984");

// save the contact
contact.save();
```

With above code, when data is viewed in android phone, the birthday is save as 29-12-6731 instead of expected 16-May-1984

we have tried all possible combinations of date entry viz: 16-May-1984 ; 16/May/1984 ; 16/5/1984 ; new date(1984,05,16)

but all in vain the results are the same.

also need to know how to save anniversary date

when using this plugin for IOS, the date saved is 15-May-1984 (1 day less than expected).

Comment: I have spent a lot of time debugging your issue but was unable to resolve it. I have even checked the Contacts plugin code as well but not able to track down the issue. I think its a cordova issue, you should register a bug over there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue is still unresolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1602

The bug you filed under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8115 does not add anything new.

As regards the date on iOS, I recommend you to set hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to 0 in the Data object.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this thing for quite a while. Found out that due to difference in milliseconds and UTC times. What worked here was adding a +1 to the date in the code and setting hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds to 0 as shown in my case.

```
     var datesplit = userDataObj.MemberDOB.split("-");
     var d = new Date(Number(datesplit[0]), Number(datesplit[1])-1,Number(datesplit[2])+1,0,0,0,0);
```